# Adding filter to Excel sheet columns using SpreadsheetGear?

Tags: excel, filter, spreadsheetgear

How to add filter to excel work sheet columns using SpreadsheetGear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "filter", I assume you mean Excel compatible "AutoFitlers".

We do not support autofilters in SpreadsheetGear 2009. We have added autofilters to SpreadsheetGear 2010 which we intend to release this summer.

Comment: So , is there  any other alternate way to implement AutoFilters without having sort features?

Comment: I have a same problem with it... donnt need the sort features...and want to change the language....